# FullCalendar event ID - how to get it for deletion of events in with Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, fullcalendar

So, I'm working on a calendar app and I'm using Laravel and FullCalendar for this.

I want to be able to delete an event - once I click on the event in the calendar, a modal popup show up with a delete button. In order to delete the event, I must know its ID, but I can't get.

I can get it via JS selectors and display it as a text, but I can't figure out how to get it as a PHP variable so that I could use it in the action parameter of the form.
The reason why I'm doing this in the way I did it is: If I get all the events and "foreach" them into the "events" array of FullCalendar, my source code when the calendar renders would be a mess, full of events and their details. By using this approach, I find that events are not displayed in the source and the page renders more quickly (but I might be mistaken).

The way I display events from the database is as follows:

**EventsController**

```
public function getEvents() 
    {
        return Event::where('event_date', '>', '2022-01-01') 
        ->join('hospitals', 'events.hospital_id', '=', 'hospitals.hospital_id')
        ->select('hospitals.hospital_color', 'hospitals.hospital_max_people', 'event_id', 'event_content', 'event_date', 'user_id')
        ->get()
        ->map(fn ($events) => [
            'id' => $events->event_id,
            'title' => $events->event_content,
            'start' => $events->event_date,
            'allDay' => true,
            'editable' => false,
            'backgroundColor' => $events->hospital_color,
            'borderColor' => $events->hospital_color,
            'hospital_max_people' => $events->hospital_max_people,
            'volunteer' => User::find($events->user_id)->first_name .' '. User::find($events->user_id)->last_name
        ]);
    }
```

**Events blade template - FullCalendar settings:**

```
<script>

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
              var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
              var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                editable: false,
                droppable: true,
                selectable: true,
                initialView: 'dayGridWeek',
                views: {
                    dayGridWeek: {
                        type: 'dayGridWeek',
                        duration: { weeks: 2 },
                        buttonText: '4 day'
                    }
                },
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,listMonth'
                },
                themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',
                locale: 'en',
                firstDay: '1',
                contentHeight: 500,
                height: 700,
                expandRows: true,
                events: 'getEvents',

                eventClick: function(calendar, jsEvent, view) {
                    $('#eventDetail').modal("show");
                    $('#id').html(calendar.event.id);
                    $('#title').html(calendar.event.title);
                    $('#start').html(moment(calendar.event.start).format('DD.MM.YYYY'));
                    $('#volunteer').html(calendar.event.extendedProps.volunteer);
                    }
            });
                calendar.render();
            });
          </script>
```

**Events blade template for showing modal:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="eventDetail" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="bar" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Event details</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Start: <p id="start"></p>
                    Volunteer: <p id="volunteer"></p>
                    Title: <p id="title"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('calendar.destroy') }}" class="needs-validation" novalidate=""></p>
                        @csrf
                        @method('DELETE')
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <x-button tabindex="3">
                                {{ __('Delete event') }}
                            </x-button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                 </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You can't get the ID _into_ the form action, when you are creating the form action _in_ PHP, long before the ID of the record to delete is known. You need to either add it into the form action via JS yourself - or submit it some other way, for example by sticking it into a hidden field.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to use .attr() selector and now my delete form actually has the ID - but now I don't know how to concatinate it with the blade syntax; if I try ```$('form').attr('action', {{calendar.destroy}}/calendar.event.id);``` - this doesn't work, neither does ```$('form').attr('action', {{calendar.destroy, calendar.event.id }});```

Comment: You can't concatenate a JS variable using Blade syntax; that's PHP, which runs _long before_ the JS variable is available. You'll have to append or replace it, like `"{{ url('/calendar/destroy') }}/" + calendar.event.id`, or `var destroyRoute = "{{ route('calendar.destroy', ['id' => ':eventId']) }}"`, then `destroyRoute.replace(':eventId', calendar.event.id)`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

So, I did it in anoter way; just wanted to post the answer - I added a hidden input field: `<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="">` and the value is filled out when a modal opens with addition of this to the original id selector: `$('#id').html(calendar.event.id).attr('value', calendar.event.id);`
I also had to alter my delete route: `Route::DELETE('calendar/destroy/{event_id}'`

And that's it. Thank you  anyway for your help